# Setting runtime depth frame rate not successful

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to set the runtime depth frame rate but it is not successful. No error is returned but the depth frame rate keeps unchanged. I used the following code the set the depth frame rate.

```
TangoErrorType SetRuntimeDepthFrameRate(uint32_t frameRate)
{
    TangoConfig runtimeConfig = TangoService_getConfig(TANGO_CONFIG_RUNTIME);
    if (runtimeConfig == nullptr) {
        LOGE("failed to get runtime config");
        return TANGO_ERROR;
    }
    TangoErrorType err = TangoConfig_setInt32(runtimeConfig, "config_runtime_depth_framerate", frameRate);
    if (err != TANGO_SUCCESS) {
        LOGE("failed to set runtime depth framerate to %d", frameRate);
        return err;
    }
    err = TangoService_setRuntimeConfig(runtimeConfig);
    if (err != TANGO_SUCCESS)
        LOGE("ailed to set runtime config");

    LOGI("the runtime depth framerate is set to %d", GetRuntimeDepthFrameRate());

    return err;
}
```

I used the following code the query the runtime depth frame rate.

```
    int GetRuntimeDepthFrameRate() const {
    TangoConfig runtimeConfig = TangoService_getConfig(TANGO_CONFIG_RUNTIME);
    if (runtimeConfig == nullptr) {
        LOGE("failed to get runtime config");
        return -1;
    }
    int32_t depthFrameRate;
    TangoErrorType err = TangoConfig_getInt32(runtimeConfig, "config_runtime_depth_framerate", &depthFrameRate);
    if (err != TANGO_SUCCESS) {
        LOGE("failed to get runtime depth framerate");
        return -1;
    }
    return depthFrameRate;
}
```

The runtime depth frame rate is never changed, it is always 5. My program keeps calling the depth callbacks when I try to set the depth rate to 0 which means the rate is not set successfully.

Is there anything wrong with what I am doing? 
Thank you for any answers in advance.

Comment: Hi Alex, are you calling the function with value higher than 5? On current Tango device, the max depth frame it can go is 5hz.

Comment: No, I only call the function with the frame rate that it is supported. Like I said, I set the framerate to 0, but the device is still scanning the depth.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but maybe it will help someone: After some experiments, I found it's still not possible to turn depth perception on/off via API at runtime using ENABLE_DEPTH_PERCEPTION_BOOL (I'm using Unity SDK). The only way to turn it on and off as needed (to save battery and cpu) is to start with depth ON and after OnTangoServiceConnected() set framerate to 0 using RUNTIME_DEPTH_FRAMERATE. Enabling it later by setting framerate to 5 again works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not able to set the frame-rate to anything else than 5, not in C++ or Java.

Tested on both Yellowstone tablet and Lenovo Phab2 Pro, Tango SDK version Wasat (Version 1.44, September 2016).